# How to verify that a method was called with Moq?

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to validate that `SetFirefoxOptions()` is called when I call `GetFirefoxDriver()`. But for whatever reason, Moq keeps telling me that it wasn't called. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldSetFirefoxOptions()
{
    var stubCapabilities = new Mock<SauceCaps>().Object;
    var mockManager = new Mock<DriverManager>();
    mockManager.Setup(
        m => m.GetFirefoxDriver(stubCapabilities)).
        Returns(It.IsAny<IWebDriver>());

    mockManager.Verify(
        m => m.SetFirefoxOptions(stubCapabilities));
}
```

DriverManager.cs:

```
public class DriverManager : IDriverManager
{
    public virtual Dictionary<string, object> SauceOptions { get; private set; }    

    public DriverManager()
    {
    }

    public virtual IWebDriver GetFirefoxDriver(SauceCaps sauceCaps)
    {
        var browserOptions = SetFirefoxOptions(sauceCaps);

        return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("https://ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub"),
            browserOptions.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
    }

    public virtual FirefoxOptions SetFirefoxOptions(SauceCaps sauceCaps)
    {
        return new FirefoxOptions
        {
            BrowserVersion = sauceCaps.BrowserVersion, 
            PlatformName = sauceCaps.Os
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "real" GetFirefoxDriver?

Comment: Debug your test, put a breakpoint over var browserOptions = SetFirefoxOptions(sauceCaps); and verify if it stops.  Check https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html, https://blog.pragmatists.com/test-doubles-fakes-mocks-and-stubs-1a7491dfa3da,

Comment: _You need to test your code.  You decide to mock it.  Now you have two problems_

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it is unclear what is your *System Under Test*. You are mocking and testing the same class at the same time. Although it is technicaly possible using **`moq`** (using CallBase) it is in principle wrong approach.

The one possibility is to extract `SetFirefoxOptions` into separate `interface` and inject it into the `DriverManager`, e.g.

```
public interface IFirefoxOptionCreator
{
    FirefoxOptions SetFirefoxOptions(SauceCaps sauceCaps);
}

public DeviceManager(IFirefoxOptionCreator optionCreator)
{
    _optionCreator = optionCreator;
}

public virtual IWebDriver GetFirefoxDriver(SauceCaps sauceCaps)
{
    var browserOptions = _optionCreator.SetFirefoxOptions(sauceCaps);

    return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("https://ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub"),
        browserOptions.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
}
```

then you could easily verify is interface method was called within your unit tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldSetFirefoxOptions()
{
    // Arrange
    var stubCapabilities = new Mock<SauceCaps>().Object;    
    var optionCreatorMock = new Mock<IFirefoxOptionCreator>();
    optionCreatorMock.Setup(m => m.SetFirefoxOptions(It.IsAny<SauceCaps>()))
                     .Returns(new FirefoxOptions());
    var sut = new DriverManager();    

    // Act
    _ = sut.GetFirefoxDriver(stubCapabilities);

    // Assert
    optionCreatorMock.Verify(m => m.SetFirefoxOptions(stubCapabilities));
}
```